# No such file or directory exists Error from server request

Tags: python, pandas, file, flask, xlrd

Actually my flask app runs fine in local host but after deploying it to server,I used pythonanywhere to deploy my flask web app it got some errors.
My motive is to send a path of a file from input and python takes the path and uses to locate the file and perform some operations on the data(excel file),if works good in local host.But in server it says no file or directory exists

```
address=request.form['address']
        file_location =address
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        psitrnid = int(sheet.cell_value(9,4))
        psiootid  = int(sheet.cell_value(9,5))
        goodtrnid = int(sheet.cell_value(9,7))
        badtrnid = int(sheet.cell_value(9,8))
        goodootid = int(sheet.cell_value(9,10))
        badootid = int(sheet.cell_value(9,11))
```

The file_location variable will have the path of file and xlrd uses it open and read it.
I don't know what is causing this error but I want to know whether we can access a local file using xlrd or pandas from server or cloud app.
Does the server perform request or the system allow the web app to take the file by mentioning the path.

Answer (score 0):

Your Flask code only has access to files that are stored on the machine where it is running; when you run it locally, it has access to files on your local machine, but if you run it on a server like PythonAnywhere, it will only have access to files that are stored on that server.  If you want people to be able to specify files on their local machine and have your code process those files, you'll need to implement code to upload the files to the server.  If you google for "upload file flask" you will find useful guides on how to do that.

Comment: Yes you are right,I just forgot the basic point.Can you send me any guide or docuementation on how to upload a file to server

Comment: Take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UploadingAndDownloadingFiles/